# Nodes, undesired pixel/glitch effect

Tags: rendering, node-editor, eevee-render-engine, procedural

Newbie here trying to make floor detailed tiles only using nodes.

The problem is that a certain point I get this effect:

[image: Pixelated / glitch effect noticiable in]

I refer to the squared glitches noticeable overall over the shine areas.

If I disconnect the node Color 2 property, this effect dissappears and all goes fine again:

[image]

IMPORTANT to know, this happens only when the Render Engine is EEVEE.
I'd like to continue rendering with Eevee while editing the nodes because is much faster, although in the final render probably I'll use Cycles.

So, what can be the reason of this problem I'm having? 
Thanks.

Blend FILE:
[image]

Comment: @RayMairlot thanks for correcting the tags.

Comment: Please upload your .blend file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and put the generated link in your question by editing it. Without being able to fiddle around it is more of a coincidence on whether we had and fixed the problem ourselves and remember it or not.

Comment: @WhatAMesh Thanks, when creating this question I though about attach the file, but then I tried with the possibilty that this were a common problem, with a fast answer. But yes, I agree always will be better including the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that this is a known issue of Blender 2.81. Seems to happen when 4 or more 3d noise texture nodes are used.

Bug details: https://developer.blender.org/T69776

With Blender 2.82 Beta works properly, at least in my case.

Comment: Can you mark your own answer as accepted?

Comment: Done, thank you.